# Equation for checking if a rectangle will fit trough a triangle shaped hole

Tags: geometry

I need to check if a rectangle will fit trough a triangle shaped hole. Is there some kind of a equation for it ?

PS. I actually need to write a program (in C) to check if a block will fit trough a triangle shaped hole. I want to try to program it myself (if I can't figure it there always is StackOverflow), I just don't know the equation (or even if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Delta ABC$ be given triangle,

$f(x,y)=0$, $g(x,y)=0$ and $h(x,y)=0$ be equations of lines $AB$, $AC$ and $BC$ respectively,

$D(p,q)$ be one of vertexes of our rectangle.

Thus, $D$ is placed inside the $\Delta ABC$ iff:
$$h(p,q)h\left(x_{A},y_{A}\right)>0,$$
$$g(p,q)g\left(x_{B},y_{B}\right)>0$$ and
$$f(p,q)f\left(x_{C},y_{C}\right)>0.$$

Now, we need to check this system for any vertexes of our rectangle.